# Reputation and username are now very close together!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, question-lists, new-nav

I've just noticed that the username and reputation you see on the question lists are now very close. I presume this is a side-effect of the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) because it only happens on MSO, SO, and MSE (here) (and not on other sites, such as [SR](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)):

[image]

It doesn't look right. There must have been a reason for there to be a space before. Why remove it? It looked [better before](http://web.archive.org/web/20150506145303/https://meta.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

---

We could either add a `margin-left` on the `reputation-score` class, or just add a `&nbsp;` between the username and rep score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed! It seems a `margin-left: 2px;` was added to the `reputation-score` class:

[image]