# New questions feed looks great, except the reputation identifier needs a space

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, new-nav

Consider this:

[image]

We need a space there! Yikes. At first I thought the user's full handle was `developingo31`. Maybe if it was a different color too that might be neat? Like a slightly lighter (or darker) gray than the "asked xxx ago"?

[image]

Comment: A regression of my previous bug report: [Reputation and username are now very close together!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257231/260841)! +1