# Name and reputation in the question list could use some spacing

Tags: bug, design, new-nav, fonts, whitespace

The space between the name of the user and its reputation could use a little bit more. It seems to be less than the other text in there.

> [image: no space]

Can my name have a little space please?

Comment: yeah... it [*was* fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257231/260841)... but it came back! :(

Comment: Just admit it, devs: you hate whitespace.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ thanks for finding this. hope it will be fixed any time soon.